# Will it be a good approach to have two separate controllers for the same micro-service?

Tags: spring-boot, microservices

I have a Spring-boot based microservice which is currently being hit from a Mobile-APP. Now we are developing a browser base client for the same microservice. Request & Response parameters between mobile-App and browser are same. Number of users in mobile-APP is around 10000 per second and for browser  is around 20000 per second. Hence, there would be more than 30000 hits to this microservice each second.

We know that "Spring controllers are singletons (there is just one instance of each controller per web application) ".

Will it be a good approach (with respect of performance) to have two separate Controllers for this same microservice, one for mobile-App users and other for browser users ?  Will it improve microservice performance by having two instances running in parallel ?

I am looking the best way to handle increasing number of hits through both the channels ?

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Comment: If the logic executed inside the controller is same there is no point in creating two controller. Every request is a separate Thread. Better thing is to scale your application onto multiple instances/ servers and add a Load balancer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When You have the same request and response, retrieved to browser and mobile clients there is no point in creating two diff controllers or services. Keep your app simple with one controller to do the job. With this your service just sees the mobile and web client in same way.

Whenever there is increase in load that has to be handled by the app, you can go for horizontal scaling, using a routing, load balancer service like zuul, nginx.
Just scale up/down the instances behind the load balancer according to the load you need to handle.